# is it possible to disable the lifting animation effect on Google Maps when dragging a marker iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a marker that I want to have more of a slide effect than a lift and drop, as I'm using it to measure distances. When a marker is lifted, by default, googleMaps moves the map slightly upward as an effect to show the marker is lifted. is there a way to turn that movement of the map itself off?

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: holeLocation, zoom: 18.0, bearing: holeH, viewingAngle: 0)
        self.gMapView.camera = camera
        self.gMapView.mapType = .satellite
        self.gMapView.settings.scrollGestures = true
        self.gMapView.settings.rotateGestures = false
        self.gMapView.settings.zoomGestures = true

let centerMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.holeCenterCoordinates)
        centerMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "mapDragCircle.png")
        centerMarker.map = self.gMapView
        centerMarker.isDraggable = true
        centerMarker.isFlat = true
```

Edit: I tried to set the GMSMapViewDelegate, and then create the following functions:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
   self.newCamera = gMapView.camera
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
    self.gMapView.camera = newCamera
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didDrag marker: GMSMarker) {
    self.gMapView.camera = self.newCamera
}
```

In order to 1. grab the current position of the map. 2. when the marker is selected, make the position of the map the idle position of the map, aka don't move the map! this piece works. the problem is the marker is still moved. I obviously can't constrain the marker's position at 'didDrag' (while it's dragging, it needs to be in motion), and at didbeginDragging, the markers position is still = the markers position before being moved.

something causes it to move in between didBeginDragging and didDrag, and I don't have a good way to counteract it.

Comment: Try Place picker of Google maps.

Comment: I’m not sure what to do with this information. Can you please be more specific?